# Grid search over a cube/sphere in R^n

Tags: python, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm trying to implement a grid search (in Python, if it matters) over a sphere in `R^n` , where `n` is unknown.

The input includes the radius and the center of the sphere, as well as a hyperparameter `theta` , that controls the resolution of the grid. I would like to express each point in this sphere as function of these three parameters.

I'm also willing to consider cube search, iterating ONLY the faces of the cube. 
(Namely, iterating the [`L_inf` sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#Balls_in_normed_vector_spaces))

If I knew that n=2, what I would do is:

```
import numpy as np

def enumerate_2d_sphere(R,theta,center=(0,0)):
    for n in xrange(int(2*np.pi / theta)+1):
        degree = n*theta
        point =(center[0]+R*np.cos(degree),center[1]+R*np.sin(degree))
        yield point

for p in enumerate_2d_sphere(1,0.1):
    print p
```

Since `n` can be arbitrarily large, I'm looking for a way to iterate over the sphere\cube efficiently.

Any ideas?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I ended up using a modified version of what strubbly suggested:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(d, center, scale=1):
    dim = len(center)
    print d/-2.0
    diff = scale * np.array([d/-2.0 for _ in xrange(dim)])
    bias = diff + center
    for i in range(dim):
        l = ([ xrange(1,d) for _ in xrange(i)] +
             [[0,d]] +
             [ xrange(d+1) for _ in xrange(dim-i-1)]
            )
        for r in itertools.product(*l):
            yield scale*np.array(r)+bias
#example for R^2:
center = (1,1.5)
data = np.array([x for x in f(20,center,scale = 0.1)])


plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1],color='r',s=100,alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(center[0], center[1],color='b',s=300,alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The output figure:

[image]

One more option, is to generate 
[uniformly distributed samples on the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points). Note that the number of samples controls the "density" (or expected density) of points:

```
import numpy as np
def generate_random_points(R,center,quantity=1000):
    """
    :param R: float
    :param center: np.array
    :param quantity: int
    """
    dim = len(center)
    for n in xrange(quantity):
        s = np.random.normal(0, 1,dim)
        r = np.sqrt(np.dot(s,s))
        s = (R/r) * s
        yield s+center
```

The worst method (in terms of simplicity and efficiency) would be to generate points on the sphere using [enumeration of n-1 angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates). The lack of efficiency follows from the need to calculated products `sin` and `cos` often (although this can be hacked too)

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want? For example suppose R=10, n=2, c=(0, 0), theta=1. What does  it mean to represent all points in this disk as a function of R, c and theta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spherical coordinates in n dimensions (see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)) or you can use the euclidean coordinates by just setting the last coordinate to be whatever is needed to get the correct radius (plus or minus).  Both of these are fine parameterizations and will give you all the points on the sphere - with the right number of parameters to iterate through.

But they don't lead naturally to a constant area (volume) element - as is easy to see by just thinking about the 3-sphere.  There is no easy solution to that problem.

I think a possible approach would be to use the n-1 dimensional grid parameterisation but to subdivide the nth component into a variable number of values depending on the volume.

The faces of the n-cube are easier: just generate the n pairs of faces where the n-th coordinate is minimal or maximal. So, for example, considering the n-cube of size 1 starting at the origin:

Set the first coordinate to zero and enumerate a grid over the remainder.  Then set it to one and do it again.  Then repeat for the second coordinate. And so on.

Here's a simple way to do that using `itertools.product`.  I have scaled the box into integer coordinates for simplicity and efficiency: you'll need to rescale and move the centre.  So `n` is the number of dimensions and `d` the number of subdivisions along each axis.

```
import itertools

def f(n,d):

    for i in range(n):
        l = ([ range(1,d-1) for _ in range(i)] +
             [[0,d-1]] +
             [ range(d) for _ in range(n-i-1)]
            )
        for r in itertools.product(*l):
            yield r

print(list(f(4,3)))
```

Comment: Example of what I meant by "scaling with the surface and not the volume" - think of an algorithm that generates all point inside a ball, and throws all points that lays in the interior of the ball. Your solution can be implemented only using recursion, right?

Comment: Well I think it would be easy with recursion but no, not needed. For example, you could use `itertools.product` or write your own equivalent..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I corrected some of your code, as it had a bug in it, you can see it in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh - well spotted - classic off by one error!  I've fixed it in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the sklearn grid search function has this option, but implementing this manually shouldn't be hard

- iterate over values of n
- for each n, iterate over n different angle parameters with theta stride from 0 to 360
- if you wan't the sphere volume, also iterate over the radius - if you want only the surface, keep the radius constant

Comment: The dimension `n` is unknown before runtime, so there can be much more angles than two...

Comment: Didn't notice this...
does it have to be the gridsearch, or is manual code also fine?

Comment: Note that in 3D one angle stride from 0 to 360 while the other from 0 to 180, and I'm not sure what happens in `n` dimensions...